# Difference between equation and align using tex4ht

Tags: equations, align, tex4ht

I'm trying to produce an html copy of my book, which is written in LaTeX using tex4ht. Things are going better than I expected. But in some places I use the equation environment and in others align. They look essentially the same in PDF, but results differ between the two environments when I use htlatex. Here is an example code sequence:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:radix}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
\end{equation}

\begin{align} \label{eq:radix}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Here are my questions:

1. In my PDF version, when should I use equation and when should I use
   align? I have used equation for showing expressions and single-line
   equations, and I have used align for continuing equations.
2. Is there a way using tex4ht to cause equation and align to produce
   the same visual results?

Question #1 is the more interesting one to me. I sell my book in both PDF and print-on-demand formats. The HTML version will be available free online, so formatting is less important. It would be nice, though, if the formatting in HTML were consistent between equation and align environments.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Did you have a question?

Comment: I don't know the answer for the first question, but you can try `pic-align` option in order to make the align look better. It seems that it is treated as inline math by default.

Comment: @michal.h21 Could you tell how?

Comment: For displays with a single equation use `equation`; for multiline displays you can choose between `gather` (no alignment) or `align` (and some other environments, actually).

Answer (score 1):

Summarising and expanding the comments.

`equation` is for single-lined numbered displays, `align` is for a multi-lined display with alignment points.  For multi-lined displays with each line centered individually use can use `gather` instead of `align`.

There is a bug report https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?179 regarding tex4ht's treatment of `align`.  Using the suggested option `pic-align`
via

```
htlatex file "htlm,pic-align"
```

nearly gives identical results on your example:

[image: Sample output]

These equations are centered on the page, but note the different placement of the equation number.